# overwriting mp4/wmv video's audio content with a new audio in C#

Tags: c#, video, audio, mp3, mp4

I have a video clip and an audio clip. I want to place the audio over a section of the video. The starting point of both match, but the video is slightly longer. I want to do this in C# preferably. Does anybody know how I can do this ? I want to batch up a huge bunch of short ( 10 -12 min clips), and so need this to be in code.

Thnx for the help.

-egon

Comment: Do you really need it in code? A command line program might do what you want, and those typically can be used on many files automatically.

Comment: I think this is what I will do now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements is a quite specific. And I can see only a one way how to solve it. In my opinion, you should follow in the way of using [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/index.html). The bad news in this case - it is a not a managed tool, so you should create/find some wrapper for using it. And good news - some wrappers already was created and bellow you can see a list of them:

1) http://www.ffmpeg-csharp.com/

2) [NET Media Handler Pro](http://www.mediasoftpro.com/media-handler-pro/5.0/csharp-sample-codes.html)

3) http://jasonjano.wordpress.com/2010/02/09/a-simple-c-wrapper-for-ffmpeg/

Comment: Thnx. But I don't really want to buy dlls. I will stick to command line prgms.